# Escaping calculations in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I wanted to draw a diagram and didn't like the fact it contains magic constants, so I tried to parametrize it. However it seems that occurences of `(1 + \N) / 2` and `\N - 2` have to be somehow escaped. What is a proper way to do it?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \N {6}

    \node (p) at ((1 + \N) / 2, -2) {};

    \foreach \i in {1, ..., \N - 2, \N} {
        \node (p\i) at (\i, 0) {};
    }

    \path foreach \i in {1, ..., \N - 2, \N} {
        (p\i) -- ($(p.center)!0.5!(p.south)$)
    };

    \node at ($(p\N - 2)!0.5!(p\N)$) {${\cdots}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Answer to the [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/345511/1)

The parentheses are syntax characters and needed to be protected in the math expression. Also, there is an additional closing parentheses that needs removing in both `\node` commands of the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\N{4}
\node at ({(1 + \N)/ 2}, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Workaround for the `\foreach` loop by calculating the number via e-TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\N{4}
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \numexpr\N - 2\relax} {
  % \typeout{i=\i}
  \node at ({(1 + \i)/ 2}, 0) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or the number can be calculated before:

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\M{\N - 2}
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \M} {}
```

## Answer to the [updated question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/345511/7)

Commented fixes of the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \N {6}

    % Term put in curly braces (argument braces), because
    % the outmost '(' and ')' serve as syntax characters.
    \node (p) at ({(1 + \N) / 2}, -2) {};

    % Workaround via e-TeX
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., \numexpr\N - 2\relax, \N} {
        \node (p\i) at (\i, 0) {};
    }

    % Another workaround by performing the calculation beforehand
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\M{\N - 2}
    \path foreach \i in {1, ..., \M, \N} {
        (p\i) -- ($(p.center)!0.5!(p.south)$)
    };

    % Inside an expandable name, pgf/TikZ math cannot be used.
    % Therefore, e-TeX performs the expandable calculation.
    \node at ($(p\the\numexpr\N - 2\relax)!0.5!(p\N)$) {${\cdots}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how to do the same in foreach range? `foreach \i in {1, ..., \N - 2}` does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but it seems that every occurence of an expression needs completely different escaping. I have reformulated the question and added full code.

Comment: @user87690 Answer to the updated question (revision 7) added. Yes, there are different ways of escaping, because the circumstances and reasons are different.

Comment: And the $\pgfmathtruncatemacro$ solution works also in the latest situation.